# Emitter Service in angular2 retriving the data in ts file using subscribe but not display the data in html

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I'm new to angular 2. In my project i have 2 compnents one is searchcomponent with text field  and another component is displayComponent. In the input field after entering some value press the enter key so that it has to display in displaycomponent by using eventemitter service (not with @input and @output).
Check with images [image: image1] [image: image2]

code is

emitter.service.ts

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {
  private static _emitters: { [channel: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {};
  static get(channel: string): EventEmitter<any> {
    if (!this._emitters[channel])
      this._emitters[channel] = new EventEmitter();
    return this._emitters[channel];
  }
}
```

searchComponent.html

```
<div>Search and clear</div>
<input type="text" value="{{inputTerm}}" (keyup.enter)="alertInput(input1.value)" #input1/>
```

searchComponent.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {EmitterService} from '../emitter.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: './Task1-search.html'
})
export class SearchComponent {

    inputTerm:string;
    menubarEmitter = EmitterService.get("displayText");

    alertInput(val1){
        this.inputTerm=val1
        alert("user clicked enter to see input value is "+this.inputTerm);
        this.menubarEmitter.emit({"InputText":this.inputTerm});
    }    
}
```

displaycomponent.html

```
<div>The name entered in input field is {{displayValue}}</div>
```

dispalycomponent.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {EmitterService} from '../emitter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'display',
  templateUrl: './Display-input.html',

})
export class DisplayComponent {

  displayValue:string;
  menubarEmitter = EmitterService.get("displayText");

  constructor(){
    this.menubarEmitter.map((res:any)=>res).subscribe(val => {
      if(val.InputText==undefined || val.InputText==""){
        // this.displayValue=val.InputText;
        console.log("wrong");
      }
      else{
        console.log("right");
        this.displayValue=val.InputText;

      }
      console.log("display "+this.displayValue);
    });
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-seed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple starter Angular2 project",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src",
    "start": "npm run server"
  },
  "contributors": [
    "Rob Wormald <robwormald@gmail.com>",
    "PatrickJS <github@gdi2290.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Angular2",
    "angular2-seed",
    "official angular 2 seed",
    "official angular2 seed"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed#readme"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {rootRouterConfig} from "./app.routes";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {GithubService} from "./github/shared/github.service";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {RepoBrowserComponent} from './github/repo-browser/repo-browser.component';
import {RepoListComponent} from './github/repo-list/repo-list.component';
import {RepoDetailComponent} from './github/repo-detail/repo-detail.component';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {SearchComponent} from "./Task1-search/Task1-search";
import {DisplayComponent} from "./Display-input/Display-input";
import {EmitterService} from "./emitter.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AboutComponent, RepoBrowserComponent, RepoListComponent, RepoDetailComponent, HomeComponent, SearchComponent, DisplayComponent],
  imports     : [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig)],
  providers   : [GithubService, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, EmitterService],
  bootstrap   : [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

app.component.ts

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector   : 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h3>
  Angular 2 Seed
</h3>
<nav>
    <!--<a [routerLink]="['/']">
    Home
  </a>
  |
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">
    About
  </a>-->
  |
  <a [routerLink]="['/search']">
    Search
  </a>
  |
  <a [routerLink]="['/display']">
    Display
  </a>
  |
    <!--<a [routerLink]="['/github', 'angular']">
    Github Repos
  </a>-->
</nav>

<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>


<footer>
  © 2016
</footer>
```

can anyone please help to resolve these issue. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you add AppComponent code? By the way, if I understand correctly what you want to achieve, consider that: 1) you are not using DependencyInjection 2) you should use Subject (or other observables) instead of EventEmitter that should be used only with componets @Output() properties 3) Use AppModule (or any module you may have) to configure Dependency Injection

Comment: @Picci i have added the app.module and app.componet files can u please check it once

Comment: Try to move the code you have in the constructor method of DisplayComponent to a new method ngOnInit(). In any case are you aware that you are using static variables and not Dependency Injection?

Comment: Can you also show AppComponent html?

Comment: I have placed the html file also u can check.

Comment: Ok, you use a router (I coul have imagined). Did u try ngOnInit()?

Comment: Yes @Picci but it is not working with using ngOnInit()

Comment: No clear idea about what is happening. If you put together a working plunkr we could have a closer look. As I said though consider that you are not using Dependency Injection and that Observables (e.g. Subject) should be used instead EventEmitter in use cases where a service has to fire events to communicate with interested subscribers. EventEmitter should be used only for @Output() properties of Components.

Answer (score 1):

Try ChangeDetectorRef

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.menubarEmitter.map((res:any)=>res).subscribe(val => {
    if(val.InputText==undefined || val.InputText=="") {
      console.log("wrong");
    } else {
      console.log("right");
      this.displayValue=val.InputText;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
    console.log("display "+this.displayValue);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eswar but the issue is not resolved. same as previous output the data is not displayed

Comment: add EmitterService to constructor and then check